# Why Black Zetsu is attached to Kaguya Ootsutsuki?

Tags: naruto

I am wondering why Black Zetsu is attached to Kaguya Ootsutsuki. If he is a part of her body then why he is taking and hiding himself inside of her arm. Who know if he is controlling her.
It seems like more than one questions so make it clear and answer the following one.

**Why Black Zetsu is attached to Kaguya Ootsutsuki**

[image]

Comment: Because the final boss always *has **something** up their sleeve*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Black Zetsu by himself is not powerful enough to take on either Sasuke or Naruto by himself. So, instead of being in the battle field, he's taking cover in Kaguya Ootsutsuki's arm (His mother).

**(As we have seen black Zetsu also has a physical body of his own, so taking that as a premise we can deduct that he is not powerful enough to take on the duo)**

I believe it's pretty clear that Kaguya is not being controlled. It's just that the will of black Zetsu matches with that of Kaguya unlike her other sons.

Black Zetsu also said (to Uchiha Madara) that he's not the will of Madara's but Kaguya's.